# keeping the child and parent relationship while traversing a json tree in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json tree of the form

```
{"reply": 0, "id": 457, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 463, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 461, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 464, "children": [{"reply": 1, "id": 467, "children": []}]}]}]}, {"reply": 0, "id": 457, "children": []}]}
```

For every node I want to keep a structure which has the
    `{node id,parent id,(immediate children of the node)`.

e.g 
`{457, none,(463,457)}`
`{463,457,(461)}`
`{461,463,(464)}`
and so on.
I am able to keep a count of the children but not knowing how to keep the parent id along with it.

```
import json
def get_children(d):
    for child in d['children']:
        yield child
        print len(child)
        for grandchild in get_children(child):
            yield grandchild
            print len(grandchild)
f=open('tree_json','r')
for line in f:
    tree=json.loads(line)
    for child in get_children(tree):
        print child['id']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a search on the tree, keeping track of the parent:

```
from collections import deque

def generate_children(tree):
    queue = deque()
    queue.append((tree, None))

    while queue:
        node, parent = queue.pop()
        children = []
        for child in node['children']:
            queue.append((child, node['id']))
            children.append(child['id'])
        yield node['id'], parent, children
```

If your data above is in a variable named `tree`, then the code gives:

```
>>> list(generate_children(tree))
[(457, None, [463, 457]),
 (457, 457, []),
 (463, 457, [461]),
 (461, 463, [464]),
 (464, 461, [467]),
 (467, 464, [])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to keep the parent id along with the child id you could try:

```
def get_children(d, parent=None, l = []):
    print (d['id'], parent, len(d['children']))
    l.append( (d['id'], parent))
    for child in d['children']:
        get_children(child, d['id'], l)
    return l
```

You get then:

```
>>> l = get_children(tree)
457 None 2
463 457 1
461 463 1
464 461 1
467 464 0
458 457 0
>>> l
[(457, None), (463, 457), (461, 463), (464, 461), (467, 464), (458, 457)]
```